# Blob upload to database failure

Tags: php, mysql, blobstorage

For some apparent reason,any image i try to upload to the database through my form,does not work.
I tried uploading other file tipes(.txt) through the same script and it works perfectly.I have tried it both on localhost and on a big server but it doesn't work.
i think that the query is too long to be processed...I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.Please help
(Please do not suggest i avoid blobs,i know the disadvantages.
Here is the code.Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $user=$_SESSION['username'];
        $image_data=file_get_contents($tmp_name);
        $query_1="UPDATE users SET profile_image='$image_data' WHERE username='$user'";
        require 'connect.php';
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$query_1)){
            echo "ok";
        }else{
            echo'error';
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can we see the SQL schema of the table in question?

Comment: What is the `enctype` attribute of your form?

Comment: What is the size of uploaded image? If it is megabytes your query size may exceed `max_allowed_packet` (i.e. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html). Try to upload really small image (i.e. 1*1px gif) to check that it is working. Also you should escape `$image_data` using `real_escape_string($image_data)`

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_image` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Comment: i have tried inserting a 2px image and it worked.but what about larger files?

Comment: What is `max_allowed_packet` for your mysql server? That (roughly) will be limit for file size.

Comment: i have already set the max_allowed packet to 32M in my.ini file